# Defining a list of strings using snowball

Tags: nlp, arabic, stemming, snowball

How can i define a list string using snowball ?

I have tried to do it like this :

```
define patterns ( 
      '{m}{f}{i}{l}' or '{f}{a}{i}{l}' or ....... 
)
```

How to get the list length ? how to deal with every pattern ?

Comment: what you want to do exactly, what list length?  what you wanna do with each pattern?

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
groupings ( v v_WXY valid_LI )

stringescapes {}

define v        'aeiouy'
define v_WXY    v + 'wxY'

define valid_LI 'cdeghkmnrt'
```

Combine strings into groupings.  Example drawn from: http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html